# Filter array where key value equals as string with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Hello I am trying to rebuild an array where the key category = DESKTOPS.
Here is an example of my array:
`$dummyData['data'][$counter] = array('item' => $A, 'ff' => $B, 'proc' => $C, 'mfgr' => $D, 'category' => $E, 'purchaseCost' => $F, 'qty' => $G);`

My array looks like this example:

```
<?php
$data =
array (
5 => 
    array (
      'item' => '600 G1',
      'ff' => 'SFF',
      'proc' => 'i5',
      'mfgr' => 'HP',
      'category' => 'DESKTOPS',
      'purchaseCost' => '$56.00',
      'qty' => '4',
    ),
    6 => 
    array (
      'item' => '90W ADAPTER',
      'ff' => '',
      'proc' => '',
      'mfgr' => 'DELL',
      'category' => 'ACCESSORIES',
      'purchaseCost' => '$10.00',
      'qty' => '1',
    ),
),
);
?>
```

in PHP how can I filter this array on `'category' => 'DESKTOPS'` only to show only DESKTOPS in the new array?

This is what I have tried:

```
foreach ($dummyData as $key => $desktops) {
         foreach(desktops as $desktop) {

           if($desktop[category] =="DESKTOPS"){
             // add to new array
             $DESKTOPS[] = array('item' => $desktop[item],'ff' => $desktop[ff],'proc' => $desktop[proc],'mfgr' => $desktop[mfgr],'category' => $desktop[category],'purchaseCost' => $desktop[purchaseCost],'qty' => $desktop[qty]);
           }

           }
}
```

But only returns this empty array:

```
Array Dump:
<?php
$data =
array (
);
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [array_filter()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to filter your array:

```
<?php

$data = array (
5 => 
    array (
      'item' => '600 G1',
      'ff' => 'SFF',
      'proc' => 'i5',
      'mfgr' => 'HP',
      'category' => 'DESKTOPS',
      'purchaseCost' => '$56.00',
      'qty' => '4',
    ),
6 => 
    array (
      'item' => '90W ADAPTER',
      'ff' => '',
      'proc' => '',
      'mfgr' => 'DELL',
      'category' => 'ACCESSORIES',
      'purchaseCost' => '$10.00',
      'qty' => '1',
    ),
);

function desktopsOnly($var) {
    return $var['category'] == "DESKTOPS";
}

$arrayDesktops = array_filter($data, "desktopsOnly");
print_r($arrayDesktops);
```

will print out:

```
Array
(
    [5] => Array
        (
            [item] => 600 G1
            [ff] => SFF
            [proc] => i5
            [mfgr] => HP
            [category] => DESKTOPS
            [purchaseCost] => $56.00
            [qty] => 4
        )
)
```

Comment: It does. When I apply it to my array $dummyData I get a blank array. Hmm. lost lol

Comment: Here is how I am building my array: https://3v4l.org/FNmV2

Comment: And in your script, `$data` is the `$data` array you posted in your question? Or where do you get that from?

Comment: Use this link hows both how the array is built and what is dumped: https://codeshare.io/5PxZDe the array is in $Dummydata

Comment: Ok, here's working code: https://3v4l.org/0blSM (I shortened your codeshare data) Not sure why you need to assemble your `$dummyData` array. One thing: your `$data` from your codeshare has a subarray `data`, so you'd need to use `$data['data']` in `array_filter()`

Comment: Ok, got it now, I think ;) I missed the first part of your codeshare. https://3v4l.org/p3V34